# $^nC_k\text{ } ^nC_r = ^nC_r\text{ }^{n-r}C_{k-r}$ - prove it

Tags: combinatorics

$^nC_k\text{ } ^nC_r = ^nC_r\text{ }^{n-r}C_{k-r}$ given $0\le r\le k\le n$ (obviously)

I'd love a combinatorial view of this, but I'll settle for Algebraic. I'm working through Russell Merris' Combinatorics book for pleasure and I'm a smidge stuck.

Would also love more info PDFs/good books (Ideally ones that don't work out at 30 pence a page, I have the library's copy)

**What have I tried**

I plowed right in with the algebra, but then I might miss out on a combinatorics solution, and the algebra doesn't go anywhere obvious.

**How it might look**

"There are (LHS) ways to choose a subset of n things of length k and another subset of length r, this is equal to..."

Comment: After **correcting** part of the expression, you should find it easy to prove either combinatorially or by manipulation. As written itis not correct.

Comment: *Prove it* - Make me! :-)

Comment: @AndréNicolas I've checked I've not written the question incorrectly, what's wrong?

Comment: If you **really** mean show $\binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{r}=\binom{n}{r}\binom{n-r}{k-r}$, the $\binom{n}{r}$ cancel, and we get $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n-r}{k-r}$. This is clearly false in general. Choose for example $n=3$, $k=2$, $r=1$. Or almost anything. If this is an assignment, there is a typo in the assignment.

Comment: @AndréNicolas it's not an assignment, I say in the question why I am doing this and where it is from. I misread (twice) this explains my difficulty!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The left-hand side should be $\binom{n}{k} \binom{k}{r}$. Then on both sides we count the number of ways to select a committee of $k$ people out of $n$ people and a subcommittee of $r$ people out of these $k$ people, either by selecting the committee first (on the left) or selecting the subcommittee first (on the right).

Answer (score 2):

$$\binom{n}{k} \binom{k}{r} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} \frac{k!}{r!(k-r)!} = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!r!(k-r)!}$$ while $$\binom{n}{r} \binom{n-r}{k-r} = \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!} \frac{(n-r)!}{(k-r)!((n-r)-(k-r))!} = \frac{n!}{r!(k-r)!(n-k)!}.$$

seems pretty equal to me.